# Using Bitly library in Scala

Tags: scala, maven, bit.ly

Unable to get scala to build after adding bitly-api-client. Below is link that points to Maven repo but it seems is missing from the repo.
https://github.com/stackmagic/bitly-api-client

I added below line to build.sbt but I keep on getting unresolved dependency.

libraryDependencies += "net.swisstech" % "bitly-api-client" % "0.8.0"

Answer (score 1):

Add below lines to build.sbt to add bit.ly-api-client

val jcenter = "Bitly repo" at "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"

resolvers+=jcenter